# How to use SEM for prediction?

Tags: r, prediction, structural-equation-modeling

I am working on a structural equation model (SEM). The goal in the model is to model the level of satisfaction with commute to work. I already fit the model to the data I have; however, what I would like to do is to predict the level of satisfaction with commute given a different data set (using the same coefficients from the original model though).

Can anyone suggest how to do that? I am proficient with `R` and am using the package `lavaan`. Also, some theoretical background or references to how to conduct such prediction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does your outcome look like? You're likely to run into the indeterminacy problem: http://psychology.okstate.edu/faculty/jgrice/factorscores/indet_q.html